# Как разобраться с якорями на сайте?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css, вкладки

Спойлер находится в отдельном блоке (Drupal 7).
Код спойлера и его содержание такие:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    if ( jQuery( '.shortcode-toggle').length ) {        
        jQuery( '.shortcode-toggle').each( function () {        
            var toggleObj = jQuery(this);   
            toggleObj.closedText = toggleObj.find( 'input[name="title_closed"]').attr( 'value' );
            toggleObj.openText = toggleObj.find( 'input[name="title_open"]').attr( 'value' );           
            // Add logic for the optional excerpt text.
            if ( toggleObj.find( 'a.more-link.read-more' ).length ) {
                toggleObj.readMoreText = toggleObj.find( 'a.more-link.read-more' ).text();
                toggleObj.readLessText = toggleObj.find( 'a.more-link.read-more' ).attr('readless');
                toggleObj.find( 'a.more-link.read-more' ).removeAttr('readless');               
                toggleObj.find( 'a.more-link' ).click( function () {                
                    var moreTextObj = jQuery( this ).next( '.more-text' );              
                    moreTextObj.animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 10).css( 'display', 'block' );
                    moreTextObj.toggleClass( 'open' ).toggleClass( 'closed' );              
                    if ( moreTextObj.hasClass( 'open') ) {                  
                        jQuery(this).text(toggleObj.readLessText);                  
                    } // End IF Statement                   
                    if ( moreTextObj.hasClass( 'closed') ) {                
                        jQuery(this).text(toggleObj.readMoreText);              
                    } // End IF Statement           
                    return false;
                });
            }

            toggleObj.find( 'input[name="title_closed"]').remove();
            toggleObj.find( 'input[name="title_open"]').remove();

            toggleObj.find( 'h4.toggle-trigger a').click( function () {

                toggleObj.find( '.toggle-content').animate({ opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle' }, 10);
                toggleObj.toggleClass( 'open' ).toggleClass( 'closed' );

                if ( toggleObj.hasClass( 'open') ) {

                    jQuery(this).text(toggleObj.openText);

                } // End IF Statement

                if ( toggleObj.hasClass( 'closed') ) {

                    jQuery(this).text(toggleObj.closedText);

                } // End IF Statement

                return false;

            });

        });

    } // End IF Statement

}); // jQuery()
</script>
<div class="shortcode-toggle toggle-show-the-content closed white border">
    <h4 class="toggle-trigger">
        <a href="#">Сравнительная таблица кровельных материалов</h4>
    <div class="toggle-content">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
ТУТ САМА ТАБЛИЦА
</table>
</div>
<input name="title_open" type="hidden" value="Сравнительная таблица кровельных материалов" /><input name="title_closed" type="hidden" value="Сравнительная таблица кровельных материалов" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в script:

```
$('.bl').click(function(e) {
    var that = this;

    $('h4.toggle-trigger a').trigger('click'); // это откроет спойлер

    e.preventDefault(); // отменяем якорь

    setTimeout(function() { // ждем, пока откроется спойлер
        location.href = that.href; // обновляем
    }, 100)
});
```

Comment: не работает.
только якорь реагирует,а спойлер не открывается(

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов у меня работает. Данный скрипт нужно добавлять после объявления скрипта спойлера, т.е. после:

![alt text][1]
  [1]: http://upyourpic.org/images/201312/m3ihlq6274.png

Comment: дружище ты просто меня выручил)
есть еще одна просьба,когда на нажимаешь на ссылку чтобы перейти по якорю и открыть спойлер,то спойлер как то дергается,это как то можно исправить?

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов хм, не заметил, чтобы он дергался. Разве что открывается не плавно.

Comment: это же можно как то исправить через .animate?

Comment: @Руслан Сабанов попробуй у animate значение 10 поставить на 200 где-то (кол-во микросекунд, сколько будет идти анимация).

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к нужному элементу id с названием якоря, например

```
<h1 id="block-block-10">Преимущества и недостатки</h1>
```

Чтобы он автоматически открывался, без javascript не обойтись будет:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
     if (this.hash) {
         $(this.hash).show();
     }
});
```